# Friend function unable to determine type in parameter

Tags: c++11

In my vector.h header file I have:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector{
private:
    int sz:
    T* buf;
public:
//member functions all the way down
friend ostream& operator << (ostream & o, const Vector & v);
};
```

In my vector.cpp file I have this:

```
#include "vector.h"
using namespace std;
//member functions defined

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Vector & v){
 return o;
}
```

I am getting a compiler error stating that "Vector" is an unknown type name in the line where operator << is defined. Could anyone help me figure out why this is? I am not allowed to change the header file.

Comment: There is no class named `Vector`. There *is* a class named (for lack of a better phrase) `Vector<T>`... but that doesn't always work so well in .cpp files. Typically you wind up either putting the templated implementation in the header file, or type-specific implementations in the .cpp. I'd strongly suggest asking your professor / teacher for insight on this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector is a template class. Hence the compiler knows no `Vector`. He only knows `Vector<...someType...>`.

So you can write something like this

```cpp
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Vector<int> & v){
 return o;
}
```

With this function, a minimal working example which doesn't modify the header would be:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    int sz;
    T* buf;

public:
    // member functions all the way down
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Vector& v);
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Vector<int>& v)
{
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    Vector<int> a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

However, to get a general offstream operator, you have to use another template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Vector<T>& v)
{
    return o;
}
```

In this case, the implementation should stay in the header. Otherwise, you can use it only in your `Vector.cpp` because templates do not produce any code until they are instantiated. As a result, every file that wants to use the operator needs to know the implementation of the template to generate the necessary code.

Also, in order to work correctly, you have to adjust the friend declaration:

```cpp
template <typename T2>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Vector<T2>& v);
```

For a smarter way to adjust the friend declaration have a look at the answer of R Sahu

Comment: Thank you for the response! I test the operator simply by cout<<firstVector<<endl; but now I am getting compiler error "undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector<int> const&)". Am I still missing something in the function definition?

Comment: I also updated the answer. Tested it myself. Without being allowed to change the header, you need to use specialized offstream operator overloads. I guess this is what you did too.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the `operator<<` function as

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Vector & v){
   return o;
}
```

does not work since `Vector` is a template, not a type. You'll have to use:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Vector<T> & v){
   return o;
}
```

However, that will reveal more problems. Note that the above implementation makes the above `operator<<` a function a template, not a function. The `friend` declaration inside the class does not use a function template. It uses a function. That's not correct.

To do this right, you'll have to:

1. Declare the class template.
2. Declare the function template.
3. Declare a specific instantiation of the function template a friend of the class template.

Here's a minimal program that works for me.

```
#include <iostream>

// Delcare the class template
template <typename T> class Vector;

// Declare the function template
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Vector<T> & v);

template <typename T>
class Vector{
   private:
      int sz;
      T* buf;
   public:
      Vector(int s) : sz(s) {}

      // Friend declaration that uses a specific instantiation of the function template.
      // Note that operator<< <int> is a function of Vector<int> only, not that
      // of Vector<double> or any other instantiaton of Vector.
      friend std::ostream& operator<< <T> (std::ostream & o, const Vector & v);
};

// Implement the function template.
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Vector<T> & v){
   return (o << v.sz);
}

int main()
{
   Vector<int> v(10);
   std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

You said,

> I am not allowed to change the header file.

That's unfortunate. Perhaps you can persuade your teacher to change their mind or update the .h file to allow a clean solution to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. It really helped me a lot.